# Eclipse doesn't browse available avds

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have created an avd with avd manager, but I can't browse it in Eclipse. The list of available avds is empty. How to solve this issue ?

[image]

here is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select "Always prompt to pick device", then go the manager and select your created AVD. Then, maybe try starting it manually. If doesn't work, download genymotion. fast and light AVD.

Comment: how can I use that avd if I can't run the code to create an apk file?

Answer (score 0):

API level of your AVD is 2.2.
If the minimum sdk level is higher than this, you cannot see your AVD at target tab.
You can create a new AVD with a higher API level(suggested) or decrease minimum sdk level.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the `minSdkVersion` of you project set to something greater than your AVD's system which is API LEVEL 8. Try to set the `minSdkVersion` of your project in `AndroidManifest.xml` to 8 and give it a try.

Comment: Try to restart eclipse, it might resolve the issue. And also restart the AVD Manager

Comment: I have restarted the computer. Nothing changed

Comment: Can you separately start the device created in AVD Manager?

Comment: Yes there are not any problems when starting it separately

Comment: Can you just edit your question and show us your manifest file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57331/discussion-between-boldizsar-zsolt-and-abrahamyan-samvel).